# Modifying Azure DevOps pipelines queue time variables

Tags: azure-pipelines

My pipeline has a queue time variable say 'RunSystemTests'. It is possible to modify these variables in a job and then access the modified variable in the next job in the same stage. In my experimentation, it appears that the changed value does not reflect in the next job. Am I missing something?

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

jobs:
  - job: SetPipelineVariables

    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        #RunSystemTests is a queue time variable
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunSystemTests]yes"
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(RunSystemTests)

  - job: ShowPipelineVariables
    dependsOn: SetPipelineVariables

    steps:
    - checkout: none    
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(RunSystemTests)
```

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let us know if the issue persists to block you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my experimentation, it appears that the changed value does not
>   reflect in the next job. Am I missing something?

The variable you set is a job-scoped variable. So its life cycle is only for current job1. We can't access it in job2. More details about job-scoped variable see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script).

To achieve what you want, you can refer to [Use outputs in a different job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job) and [Set a multi-job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable).